# for doesn't check second condition

Tags: c, for-loop

You can see my code below. I'm trying to check whether the sum of the entered numbers is above 100 or one of the entered numbers is above 20. If one of these happens the program should quit. If I enter numbers so the sum is higher than 100 the program quits. But if I enter a number higher than 20 the program just continues to run.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    int numbers;
    int sum = 0;

    printf("Please enter numbers:\n");

    for (numbers = 0; sum < 100 || numbers < 20; numbers++) {
        scanf("%d", &numbers);
        sum += numbers;
    }
    printf("Sum: %d\n", sum);


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If one of these happens the program should quit

You want `&&` then, not `||`. Think about it; if either `sum` is less than 100 or `numbers` is less than 20, your program continues. So, when you enter a value for `numbers` greater than 20, your code will continue to run until and unless `sum` is also greater than 100.